# Positive definite matrix for complex vectorial space

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, positive-definite

I have problems when building a positive definite matrix on a complex vectorial space. I came across this problem when testing an optimization algorithm, despite its theory only considers the real case.

This is my situation:

Let $\tau, \sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x, y, k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.
Also $\tau, \sigma > 0$

I have this matrix:
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{\tau} & -k_2 \\
  -k_1 & \frac{1}{\sigma}
 \end{bmatrix}$$

and I have this vector
$$v = \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y
 \end{bmatrix}$$
In this context, I want to find values for $\tau$ and $\sigma$ that make $M$ positive definite with respect to $v$ ($v^H$ is its Hermitian transform). When I make the calculations I get:
$$v^H Mv = \frac{x^Hx}{\tau} + \frac{y^Hy}{\sigma} - x^Hk_1y - y^Hk_2x > 0$$
$$\frac{x^Hx}{\tau} + \frac{y^Hy}{\sigma} > x^Hk_1y + y^Hk_2x$$
Here I have to compare a real value (to the left of the equation) and a complex value (to the right). I read somewhere that this kind of comparison is not defined in the complex case, [even matlab considers only the real part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371634/comparison-of-complex-numbers-in-matlab).

I'm stuck here. Is it a correct approach to take the norm of both sides?
$$\frac{\|x^Hx\|}{\tau} + \frac{\|y^Hy\|}{\sigma} > \|x^Hk_1y + y^Hk_2x\|$$

Comment: maybe you want to consider: $$\mathrm{Re}\left\{\frac{x^Hx}{\tau} + \frac{y^Hy}{\sigma} \right\}> \mathrm{Re}\{x^Hk_1y + y^Hk_2x\}$$ and $\mathrm{Im}\{x^Hk_1y + y^Hk_2x\}=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that taking the norms is a valid approach. The inequality stays valid, but I'm not sure that you will obtain the tightest possible bounds on $\tau$ and $\sigma$.

Edit: Since the LHS will be a scalar, I think you may need to place the norm outside the entire LHS expression.

Comment: This is what actually worked in my case :)

Comment: woohoo! I love matrix math

Comment: me too, I'm learning a lot. The reason I didn't put the norm outside the LHS is the triangle inequality because it made things easier in my source code: $\frac{\|x^Hx\|}{\tau} + \frac{\|y^Hy\|}{\sigma} \geq \|\frac{x^Hx}{\tau} + \frac{y^Hy}{\sigma}\| > \|x^Hk_1y + y^Hk_2x\|$.

Comment: Nice. What about the $\tau$ and $\sigma$ in the denominators? Wouldn't those need norms as well?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add the condition $\tau, \sigma > 0$ so $\|\frac{x^Hx}{\tau}\| = \frac{\|x^Hx\|}{\tau}$. I edited the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are $u=\overline{x}yk_1+x\overline{y}k_2\in \mathbb{R}$ and $w=||x||^2/\tau+||y||^2/\sigma>u$.

Let $v=x\overline{y}(k_2-\overline{k_1})$;  one can see that $v\in\mathbb{R}$ IFF $u\in\mathbb{R}$.

If $k_2-\overline{k_1}=re^{i\theta}$, then necessarily $(*)$ $x\overline{y}$ is in the form $se^{-i\theta}$. If it's not the case, then no solutions.

If it's the case, then, to satisfy the second inequality, it suffices to choose $\tau,\sigma$ positive and small enough.